# .Find function and Offset cells working for constants but not formulas

Tags: vba, excel, offset, vlookup

The following code is similar to a Vlookup function. Was wondering why the same For Each...Next loop works when applied to Constants but not when it's applied to Formulas.

Thank you

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim SourceRange As Range, TargetRange As Range, TargetCell As Range, 
Dim SourceCell As Range, SourceColumn As Range, TargetColumn As Range, 
Dim TargetRangeConstant As Range, TargetRangeFormula As Range

On Error Resume Next

'set Worksheets and Ranges
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set SourceRange = ws1.Range("A:A")
Set TargetRange = ws2.Range("L:L")
    
Set SourceColumn = ws1.Range("C:C")
Set TargetColumn = ws2.Range("O:O")
  
Set TargetRangeConstant = TargetRange.SpecialCells(xlConstants)
Set TargetRangeFormula = TargetRange.SpecialCells(xlFormulas)

'For Constants
For Each TargetCell In TargetRangeConstant
    Set SourceCell = SourceRange.Find(What:=TargetCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not TargetCell Is Nothing Then
        '"copies" cells in source to target
        TargetCell.Offset(, TargetColumn.Column - TargetRange.Column) = SourceCell.Offset(, SourceColumn.Column - SourceRange.Column)
    End If
Next
 
'Same Function but for Formulas
 For Each TargetCell In TargetRangeFormula
    Set SourceCell = SourceRange.Find(What:=TargetCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not TargetCell Is Nothing Then
        '"copies" cells in source to target
        **TargetCell.Offset(, TargetColumn.Column - TargetRange.Column) = SourceCell.Offset(, SourceColumn.Column - SourceRange.Column)**
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `TargetCell.Formula` in the second block. In my sample code below, A1 in Sheet1 has `=SUM(B1:C1)`. In Sheet2, it is in D1. It returns the correct address.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim TargetCell As Range
    Dim TargetF, TestS As String
    Set TargetCell = Sheet1.Range("A1")
    TargetF = TargetCell.Formula
    TestS = Sheet2.Cells.Find(What:=TargetF, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Address
    MsgBox TestS 'Returns D1.
End Sub
```

Let us know if this works.

Comment: Thanks alot! It worked like magic when I execute the code in the workbook. Edited the TargetCell to TargetCell.Formula in the .Find function.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please accept the above as an answer if it has been helpful by clicking on the check icon. Thanks! :)